# How to explain use of "что" when a person is being referred to in songs?

Tags: грамматика

I roughly understand that "кто" is used when referring to a person and "что" when referring to a thing, but I've found at least three examples in songs where this doesn't seem to be the case. I include YouTube links at the exact timestamp where this happens:

"Из вагантов" https://youtu.be/fAHWvUANVCg?t=105s

> Если те профессора,
> **Что** студентов учат

"Чиж & Co - Вечная молодость" https://youtu.be/dGsEzJ0S1-E?t=60s

> Еще была солистка Леночка 
> Та, **что** училась на год младше

"Бумбокс - Та Что" https://youtu.be/9jFOKH3brQc?t=40s

> Та, **что** была со мной, где ты теперь?

It seems [this](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12763/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-used-as-a-relative-to-a-personal-noun-antecedent) question is related, but the answer is too technical for me to understand if/how it applies to the above examples.

I'm looking for a simple explanation of how to interpret the above lyrics.

Comment: this will be better : https://youtu.be/Vu4Ru0DFu-E :>

Comment: "he who fights with monsters" or "she who became the sun" can be translated like "тот, что" / "та, что".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Что* in this context is a relative pronoun, corresponding to English "who", "that" or "which".

> - If those professors **that** teach the students…
> - There also was Lena, the lead singer, **who** was a grade younger
> - You (*literally, "that (woman)"*), **who** were with me, where are you now?

This usage is a little bit dated, and a Modern Russian speaker would probably use *который* ("which") instead of *что* in these phrases. But in poetry and grand style texts, it's perfectly ok to use it.

Apparently, "which" used to work as a personal relative pronoun in English as well, up until early Modern English. In KJV, the Lord's prayer reads: "Our Father which art in heaven".